# Push notification not working Android

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

am trying to implement push notification on my app. I am sending message to GCM using php code. Its returning the following message.

```
{"multicast_id":5310811111183606373,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1345484510809261%00fbb339d652b5b3"}]}
```

But push notification is not coming to my android device. Anything wrong from my side ?

permissions in Android manifest is given below ..

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.projects.XXXX.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.projects.XXX" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<permission
    android:name="com.projects.xxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.projects.xxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.projects.xxxx.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Broadcast receiver

```
public class GcmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    if(message != null){

        generateNotification(context, message);
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @Sid php code? manifest is pasted above..

Comment: Post your Android Code.

Comment: Put breakpoint inside onReceive() method and debug and check whether you can generate Notification or not.

Comment: Are you working on emulator? if so you must need to work with android 4.2 or later. If you are working on device, then which google_play_service you are using, I mean if you are working on 2.2, you need to use google_play_services_frayo, if greater then uses simple google_play_service.

Comment: @Adnan am using Android device with android 4.3

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Are you using some restricted internet?

Comment: In my case I face this problem due to a firewall on the network which blocked URLs and ports of GCM. I solve it temporarily by using a VPN service i.e. Hotspot.

To solve permanently I allowed following ports and URLs on firewall.

5228 5229 5230

All IPs which are listed in Google's ASN of 15169